# QuillJS - remove formatting when pasting into the editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, quill, react-quill, react-quilljs

I previously used https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1184#issuecomment-403657128 to make sure that no one can paste formatted text in the QuillJS editor, because I would like people to only use the few editing buttons that I enabled from QuillJs. Since then, it stopped working for me. My question is:

- is this working for everyone else?
- if no, do you know of an alternative?

Comment: Yes, this `PlainClipboard` code still works fine for me with QuillJS 1.3.7. I'm using it in a Vaadin 14 environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stopped working for me"? What does work and what does not work? Is a user able to paste text into the editor? Is the pasted text formatted or not formatted? ...? Please give some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing about https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1184#issuecomment-403657128 that may behave different than you may have expected could be the `'silent'`.

"APIs causing text to change may also be called with a "silent" source, in which case text-change will not be emitted. This is not recommended as it will likely break the undo stack and other functions that rely on a full record of text changes." [ https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#events ]

So if you expected to get the `text-change` event get emitted but do not get it, then change these two lines

```
this.quill.updateContents(delta, 'silent')
this.quill.setSelection(index, length, 'silent')
```

like this:

```
this.quill.updateContents(delta, 'user')
this.quill.setSelection(index, length, 'user')
```

Then the `text-change` event will get fired.